# How to make a query to check the value of a field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
-----------------------------------------------
code  intvalue        checkrole         result
-----------------------------------------------

A01    14             A02-A03           true
A02    24             A04               false
A03    10             A04               false
A04    12             A02/2             true
```

I would like to fill the column result with a query or sp, based on the role described into the column checkrole, something like Excel, any ideas?

I apologize to everyone, I explained myself wrongly.
For example:
A01 14 A02-A03 true
in this case, I would like to interpret the role and get 24-10 = 14 ie true

UPDATE 2:
Hello everyone and thanks for your interest. HABO, I'm working in this direction "substitute the values ​​into the expression (" 24-10 ") ....":

TBL

```
code intValue checkRule                   result
A01  14       select A02-A03 from Table_1 NULL
A02  24       select A04 from Table_1     NULL
A03  10       select A04 from Table_1     NULL
A04  12       select A02 / 2 from Table_1 NULL
```

SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo]. [Test]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @code VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @intvalue INT
DECLARE @checkrule VARCHAR (50)

DECLARE @cTbl AS CURSOR
SET @cTbl = CURSOR FOR SELECT code
, intValue
, checkRule
FROM [dbo]. [Table_1]

OPEN @cTbl FETCH NEXT FROM @cTbl INTO @code, @intvalue, @checkrule
WHILE @@ FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

declare @statement nvarchar (4000), @Result int, @Parm nvarchar (20)
SET @statement = 'select @Result = 11 + 7'
SET @Parm = '@Result int output'
EXEC sp_executesql @statement, @Parm, @ Result OUT
print @Result

FETCH NEXT FROM @cTbl INTO @code, @intvalue, @checkrule
END
CLOSE @cTbl
DEALLOCATE @cTbl
END
```

UPDATE 3:
It was what I was looking for. I'm not an expert, but I learn from mistakes and I thank those who teach me something new, thanks to all those who participated, and above all thanks to HOBO, good evening

Comment: sqlfiddle.com with data would be awesome

Comment: You're probably after a SELECT CASE statement

Comment: What you want is not going to be easy. Any particular reason you want to do this in `SQL Server` ?

Comment: It appears that you want to treat `checkrole` as an expression to be evaluated using `intvalue` values looked up from other rows. In your example the `checkrole` for `code` "A01" is "A02-A03", so lookup the `intvalue` for "A02" (24) and "A03" (10), substitute the values into the expression ("24-10") and evaluate the expression to arrive at 14. (It isn't clear how you get from `14` to `true`.) To some extent it will depend on the complexity of the expressions allowed in `checkrole`, e.g. can you have trigonometric functions or just simple arithmetic. ...

Comment: ... You need to (1) parse the "variable" names, e.g. "A04", out of the expression, (2) lookup the values, (3) substitute the values and (4) evaluate the expression. SQL can do (2) and (4) (using _dynamic SQL_) with some grace. Steps (1) and (3) won't be quite so pretty. Or perhaps I misunderstood your intent. (As for `14` being `true`, I thought that [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)) was the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write a function that would create a list of values from your checkRole (eg it would give me list 'A02', 'A03', 'A04' from A02-A04 and then I would write an update statement with 'contains' statement in it

Answer (score 0):

using the table that you show you can update the values of result column with the next query

```
UPDATE TableName
  SET result = CASE
    WHEN checkrole = 'A02-A03' THEN "true"
    WHEN checkrole = 'A04' THEN "false"
    WHEN checkrole = 'A02/2' THEN "true"
    ELSE "setDefaultValue" 
    END
WHERE code  in (A01,A02,A03,A04);
```

at the last line you specify the code value of row to update. If you execute this query with the column result empty, it will complete the table and result into the same data as the one you post above.

(The query work good on Mysql)

Answer (score 0):

**Executive Summary**: This is a terrible idea. Back away slowly and no one gets hurt.

*Disclaimer: I'm not responsible for the costs of any therapy required after reading beyond this point.*

From your Update 2 it appears that you have control over the format of `CheckRule`. It is much easier to require that the user delimit the `Code`s, e.g. using `'«A04»'` rather than `'A04'`, instead of trying to find them using TSQL. You don't need to worry about problems like substituting `'A02'` with `66` when the `CheckRule` is `'A026 - BA02'` and getting `'666 - B66'`.

What follows is simply dreadful. It demonstrates a brute force approach to taking expressions with delimited "variables", e.g. `'«A04»'`, replacing all occurrences of each "variable" with its integer value, evaluating the resulting expression and retrieving the result.

Instead of using something as distasteful as a cursor, it uses two nested cursors to waddle through the `CheckRule`s and `Code`s. It would be more efficient to parse the "variables" out of the expression and substitute values as needed rather than using a try-everything approach, but TSQL doesn't excel at implementing [parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser).

For extra credit it also brings along the blessing of embracing [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Try a `CheckRule` like `'A01; select 1 / 0;'`. Don't try one like `'-1; drop database LuckyGuess;'`.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table
  ( SampleId Int Identity, Code NVarChar(8), IntValue Int, CheckRule NVarChar(64), Result Bit );
insert into @Samples ( Code, IntValue, CheckRule ) values
  ( N'A01', 14, N'«A02» - «A03»' ),
  ( N'A02', 24, N'«A04»' ),
  ( N'A03', 10, N'«A04»' ),
  ( N'A04', 12, N'«A02» / 2' );
select * from @Samples;

-- Process the data.
declare Oy cursor forward_only fast_forward read_only
  for select SampleId, Code, IntValue, CheckRule from @Samples;
declare @SampleId as Int, @Code as NVarChar(8), @IntValue as Int, @CheckRule as NVarChar(64);

declare Vey cursor forward_only fast_forward read_only
  for select Code, IntValue from @Samples;
declare @VariableCode as NVarChar(8), @VariableIntValue as Int

-- For each row's   CheckRule ...
open Oy;
fetch next from Oy into @SampleId, @Code, @IntValue, @CheckRule;
while @@Fetch_Status = 0
  begin
  -- Copy the   CheckRule   so that we can build the   @Expression   to evaluate.
  declare @Expression as NVarChar(64) = @CheckRule;
  -- For each   Code   that could appear in an   @Expression ...
  open Vey;
  fetch next from Vey into @VariableCode, @VariableIntValue;
  while @@Fetch_Status = 0
    begin
    -- Replace any occurrences of the   Code   in the   @Expression   with the corresponding integer value.
    set @Expression = Replace( @Expression, N'«' + @VariableCode + N'»',
      Cast( @VariableIntValue as NVarChar(10) ) );
    fetch next from Vey into @VariableCode, @VariableIntValue;
    end;
  close Vey;
  -- Make the   @Expression   an executable statement.
  set @Expression = N'set @IntResult = ' + @Expression;
  declare @Result as Int;
  -- Evaluate the   @Expression   and get the   @Result .
  execute sp_executesql @Expression, N'@IntResult Int output', @IntResult = @Result output;
  select @SampleId as SampleId, @Code as Code, @IntValue as IntValue, @CheckRule as CheckRule,
    @Expression as Expression, @Result as Result;
  fetch next from Oy into @SampleId, @Code, @IntValue, @CheckRule;
  end;

close Oy;
deallocate Oy;
```

In the event it isn't clear, don't. Just don't.